# when do two elements generate a p-group?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, permutations, symmetric-groups

Consider the symmetric group $S_n$, and let $x,y \in S_n$ such that $x$ has order $p^k$, and y has order $p^l$ for some prime $p$, and positive integers $k,l$. Can we give any kind of precise conditions on $x,y$ to ensure that the group $<x,y>$ is a $p$-group? Of course, if you fix a 2-generated $p$-group, and impose the relations in its presentation as conditions on $x,y$, then you definitely get a p-group. Or, same when $x$ and $y$ commute. But, my question is not quite that. I was wondering if there are more general conditions (without fixing any $p$-group in mind) that make $<x,y>$ a $p$-group for sure.

Comment: If there are $a$ and $b$ for which $yx=x^ay^b$ then it will be a $p$-group. (Since we're quantifying over $a$ and $b$, this technically isn't imposing "a" relation.) Is this the kind of thing you wanted? If you wanted something that does not involve relations, then what kind of conditions on $x$ and $y$ would you even accept?

Comment: Thanks. You're right, this definitely works. As for what I really meant, sorry that it was a bit vague. I guess what I was roughly wondering was- fixing the order of $x$ and $y$, if there is any if and only if characterization of such $x$ and $y$, rather than some conditions that give only some families of cases. But, I realized maybe I'm asking for too much.

Answer (score 1):

If $xy=yx$ then it will be a $p$-group.

Comment: Thanks. I think I had to explicitly exlude that obvious case too, when I was excluding the possibilty of imposing presentation relations. I was looking for more general conditions that strictly contain commutativity. I edited the question.